# How do I truncate file paths within a binary's symbols?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

When compiling a rust project via cargo, even in release mode, it generates a pdb file, and the full path (Including my username, which has my real name) can be found in it. Is there a way to truncate these file names, or even better, not use external files at all?

Comment: I assume you've already thought of some of the the more obvious methods, like working in a different path, adding a new user, using a generic VM / container, letting the binaries you intend to be published be built on CI, or just not publish that pdb file?

Answer (score 3):

To remove generation of PDB files, add this to your `Cargo.toml` file:

```ini
[profile.release]
debug = false
```

If you want to generate the PDB file, but not to include debugging symbols in the PDB file, use `debug = 1` instead of false.

Comment: `debug = 0` is completely equal to `debug = false`.

Comment: Yes, it was meant to be 1, for basic optimizations. Thanks!